# Methods for numerically calculating families of ON polynomials given inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, numerical-methods, soft-question, orthogonal-polynomials

I am aware of some famous families of polynomials, for example Bessel, Jacobi, Chebyshev, Hermite and so on. They have one thing in common : they are all ON bases $\{P_0,P_1,\cdots\}$ with respect to their own specific integral inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle_g$. In other words, they have their own characteristic $g$ function, so that:

$$\langle P_n,P_m \rangle_g  =\int_{-\infty}^\infty P_n(t)\cdot P_m(t)\cdot g(t) dt\\[0.75cm]\text{so that}\\[0.5cm]\langle P_n,P_m\rangle _g = \delta_{n-m}$$

Now to my question : given some known $g$, what methods exist to numerically calculate new such families of polynomials $\{P(k)\}$.

Comment: please use \langle \rangle for angle brackets

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown yes you are right, it  looks better.

Comment: Gram-Schmidt? $\ $

Comment: @cmk Good idea ! I did not even think about it, but it should work, of course.

Comment: I realized I would want to add  a new constraint, just hoping no one is typing a looong answer which that edit would invalidate.

Comment: Maybe the three-term recursion could also be useful? (Just an idea, I haven't really thought about it.)

Comment: I am aware of some specific recursive formulas for some of these families which can be derived, but there also exists a generic one, @HansLundmark ?

Comment: Yes, it follows from orthogonality that $x \, p_{n}(x)$ is a linear combination of $p_{n+1}(x)$, $p_n(x)$ and $p_{n-1}(x)$. Just google "orthogonal polynomial three-term recursion" for more info.

Comment: @HansLundmark : Very interesting! Thank you. I just realized a little too late that I also wanted some kind of maximal sparsity of coefficients. So that mean order of polynomials is minimized or something like that. Gram-Schmidt does not guarantee any degree of sparsity.

Comment: Orthogonality (together with the usual requirement that $P_n$ has degree $n$) already determines the sequence of polynomials uniquely up to normalization factors, so there's not much you can do about sparsity of coefficients.

Comment: Yes this requirement that $P_n$ has degree $n$ is what I meant with sparsity, but I suppose this can be achieved with Gram-Schmidt by only randomizing the first $N$ coefficients and setting rest to $0$?